# how to compute tic-tac-toe board and find out match_status in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created a javascript for tic-tak-toe.the input is given to the html using $('td').text("X")and$('td').text("O") for 2player,also i declared an array of winning combination.Now my problem is how to validate(function match_status() the board and determine the winner/loser or the match is drawn

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
    $('td').on('click',function(event)
    {
        if(count%2!=0)
        {
            $(this).text("X");
            $("p").toggle('fast', function(){
                    $("h2").text('player one');
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).text("O");
            $("p").toggle('fast', function(){
                    $("h2").text('player two');
                    });
        }
        count++;
        checkboard(this.id);
    });
//td ids
var wins = [["#0","#1","#2"], ["#3","#4","#5"], ["#6","#7","#8"], ["#0","#4","#8"], ["#2","#4","#6"], ["#0","#3","#6"], ["#1","#4","#7"], ["#2","#5","#8"]];
function checkboard()
{


for (var i=0; i<wins.length; i++)
    {           
        var w = wins[i];            
                var checkXwin = $(w[0].val()) == "X" && w[1].val() == "X" && w[2].val() == "X";
                var checkOwin = w[0].val() == "O" && w[1].val() == "O" && w[2].val() == "O";
        if (checkXwin)
        {
            alert("X Wins!");
        }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem a little probleme... what have you tried?°

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Show your code, what you have tried, where exactly the problem lies? What does your validate function currently look like?

Comment: Ok, we're getting somewhere. Can you replace `// code here` with what you think should go there? Or what you tried? Don't worry, if that try doesn't work, it will at least show us how you're thinking about approaching the problem, and will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in the checkBoard function.

Change `$(w[0].val())` to `$(w[0]).text()`. The `$(w[0])` will pick the element by id, and `.text()` will pick the text without any formatting - so X or O in your case. Do that for each check. And I do mean each check. `w[1].val() == "X"` is incorrect. `w[1]` is a string, not an object.

The difference is that `$(w[0].val())` is not an element, but `$(w[0])` is, and then you can get the text from this element.